# Firefox Getting exception Element is not clickable at point (461.5, 65) tried all the solutions

Tags: java, firefox, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am testing "http://www.khuranatravel.com/"

The scenario is I hover over the date pallet, select a date and click on search buses button. But I am getting aforementioned exception

I tried following solutions

1. explicit wait (presenceOfElement, visibilityOf, visibilityOfElementLocatedBy)
2. Javascript executor - js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webelement);
3. Javascript executor - js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, "+webelement.getLocation().x+")");
4. js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", webelement);
5. Tried with actions- moveToElement

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
   Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
   JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   builder.moveToElement(we2).perform();
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(we2)); 
   builder.moveToElement(we2).click();
   ```
6. I have also tried with maximizing window but nothing seems to be working

Please provide solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this working after a lot of testing

```
public static void selectDate(){
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
//      WebElement we=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'ui-datepicker') and @data-handler='selectDay']/a[contains(.,'10')]"));
        Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
        driver.findElement(By.id("departDate")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class, ' ui-datepicker')]/child::a[contains(@class,'ui-state')][contains(text(), '10')]")));
        builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class, ' ui-datepicker')]/child::a[contains(@class,'ui-state')][contains(text(), '10')]"))).click().perform();
        boolean result = false;
        int attempts = 0;
        while(attempts < 10) {
            try {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class, ' ui-datepicker')]/child::a[contains(@class,'ui-state')][contains(text(), '10')]")).click();
                result = true;
                break;
            } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            }
            attempts++;
        }
```

I was getting StaleElementReferenceException after hovering over. So wrote extra code to handle exception and click until the element gets refreshed.

I debugged through WebDriverException and StaleElementReferenceException to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Hi Element is not clickable at point (461.5, 65) This happens when the element is loaded into the DOM, but the position is not fixed on the UI. There can be some other divs or images or ads that are not loaded completely.
below find the solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        /*System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\eclipseProject\\StackOverFlow\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();*/

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.khuranatravel.com/");

// error reported by you (i never got error at this point)
// Getting exception Element is not clickable at point (461.5, 65)
// instead of clicking depart date i will perform some 
// extra step to give element time to take fixed position inside the DOM

List<WebElement> mymenu = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='left']/a"));
        for(int i=0;i<mymenu.size();i++){System.out.println(mymenu.get(i).getText());};

// clcik on depart date now 
driver.findElement(By.id("departDate")).click();

        // take journey date in list
        List<WebElement> mydate = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-month='3']/a"));
        // pass the date on which you want to travel
        String journeydate = "10";
        for(int i=0;i<mydate.size();i++){
            System.out.println("values are in date : " + mydate.get(i).getText());
            if(mydate.get(i).getText().equals(journeydate)){
                mydate.get(i).click();
                break;
            }

        }
        // click to activate the return date calendar
        // and here the error reported by you comes
        // Getting exception Element is not clickable at point (461.5, 65)
        // as you have mentioned that you have tried everything so i will do a work around
        // instead of clicking return date just after journey date i will perform some 
        // extra step to give element time to take fixed position inside the DOM

        List<WebElement> mymenu = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='left']/a"));
        for(int i=0;i<mymenu.size();i++){System.out.println(mymenu.get(i).getText());};

        // now click to activate the return date calendar
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@type='text']")).get(1).click();


        // pass the date on which you want to travel
        String returnOn = "20";
        mydate = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-month='3']/a"));
        for(int i=0;i<mydate.size();i++){
            System.out.println("values are in date : " + mydate.get(i).getText());
            if(mydate.get(i).getText().equals(returnOn)){
                mydate.get(i).click();
            }
        }
        // click on the search button
        driver.findElement(By.id("submitSearch")).click();

    }
```

I have update the answer above is working on Chrome as well as firefox hope this helps you

Comment: The exception is coming at depart date.

Comment: i never get any exception at depart date anyways please do apply the same logic (what i have applied at return date) it will surely help.

Comment: I am still getting same error even with your code. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I find your approach from nikhil udgirkar is working better and more stable rather using JS executor (C# code attached)

```
var element = Driver.FindElement(By.Id(someId));
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```